# How to Pass gridview value in to another page Dropdown (How to change Dropdown selected value dynamically )

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a grid view report view with EDIT link button. When I click the button, the page redirects to another update page with the CURRENT DATA from gridview. For Text box, it works fine, but I can't do the same for the drop-down.

I've tried this:

```
ddnAssinedBy.SelectedValue = gvAction.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;    
ddnAssinedBy.Items.FindByValue(gvAction.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text).Selected = true;
```

But it is not working.

Comment: please provide more information. How do we know what are you sending and how ?

Answer (score 0):

In your edit linkbutton event , get values you need and put them in session like

Session["current-selection"] =gvAction.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

On another page use this value set selection in dropdown.

Another option is to pass value in query string when you redirect and fetch it on another page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

ddnAssinedBy.**SelectedItem.Text**= gvAction.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

or

ddnAssinedBy.Items.**FindByText**(gvAction.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text).Selected = true;

but first you have **to disable selected item**

ddnAssinedBy.SelectedItem.Selected= false;